# Frame a jack stud without bottom plate?

Tags: framing, vent, structural, engineering, framing-fasteners

I need to frame a small header in my kitchen exterior wall for a range hood exhaust because the 8" hole is dead center on a stud (of course). It's a 2 story 1941 house with 2x4s 16 on center.

The problem is there is no bottom plate on the left wall cavity for the jack stud to sit on due to a furnace return duct. (getting rerouted)

I can't really open up the wall any further without removing cabinetry. Seems like I have 2 options.

1. Add the jack stud using structural screws to attach the king stud. Probably also toenail the header.
2. No jack stud, attach header with a structural L bracket.

Am I overthinking this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Accelerate the rerouting of the return duct? Or delay hood installation until the return duct is rerouted?

Comment: A header for an 8” hole? I would frame around it but I doubt I would go that far.

Comment: I would just frame around it if I had a top or bottom plate on the left side. Maybe I'll just add an LVL 2x4 or two on the right side and call it a day. Nobody I'm talking to seems to think it's a big deal so it's probably not.